# hadoop pig join using datetime field

Tags: join, hadoop, apache-pig

I have two data sets

```
messages.txt
2014-06-23 08:42:34, 34569
2014-06-23 08:42:35, 23945
2014-06-23 08:42:36, 45673
... etc

CPU.txt
2014-06-23 08:42:34, 99
2014-06-23 08:42:35, 80
2014-06-23 08:42:36, 83
... etc
```

Id like to join the tables using the timestamp, which I want to format as datetime

This is my attempt

```
MSG= load 'messages.txt' using pigstorage(',') as (date_time:chararray, msg_recv:int);
CPU= load 'CPU.txt' using pigstorage(',') as (date_time:chararray, cpu:int);
MSG_FORMATED = foreach MSG GENERATE ToDate(date_time, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as date_time, msg_recv;
CPU_FORMATED = foreach CPU GENERATE ToDate(date_time, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as date_time, cpu;
```

So far so good

I can dump MSG_FORMATED and CPU_FORMATED and see they are in datetime format

```
dump MSG_FORMATED;
2014-06-23T08:42:34.000-04:00, 34569
2014-06-23T08:42:35.000-04:00, 23945
2014-06-23T08:42:36.000-04:00, 45673

dump CPU_FORMATED;
2014-06-23T08:42:34.000-04:00, 99
2014-06-23T08:42:35.000-04:00, 80
2014-06-23T08:42:36.000-04:00, 83
```

now my problem when I try to join!

(which should be fairly straight forward ? )

```
COMBINED = JOIN MSG_FORMATED BY date_time, CPU_FORMATED by date_time;
describe COMBINED; 
COMBINED: {MSG_FORMATED::date_time: datetime, MSG_FORMATED::msg_recv: int, CPU_FORMATED::date_time: datetime, CPU_FORMATED::cpu: int}
```

dump COMBINED;

throws an error

```
2014-07-01 13:10:23,065 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
2014-07-01 13:10:23,065 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf - The variable mapred.child.ulimit is no longer used.
2014-07-01 13:10:23,070 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: AttemptID:attempt_1400260444475_25479_r_000000_3 Info:Error: org.joda.time.DateTime.compareTo(Lorg/joda/time/ReadableInstant;)
```

Comment: Got any solution or still open ?

Answer (score 0):

You can JOIN the tables using the timestamp, and after that you format it to datetime.

Comment: SO is it not possible to JOIN on datetime ?
going forward im going to have raw timestamps in slightly different formats.
toDate was great as it would normalize them.

Comment: Yes i think PIG doesn't like JOIN on datetime ! if you want to do that you could convert tostring (chararray) before the JOIN.